# php datetime-local format replace can you help me?

Tags: php, string, date, replace

can you please help me? 
i need to change

```
2017-12-31 11:45:00
```

to

```
2017-12-31T11:45
```

using php function.

I need this datetime-local format for putting in a input value.

Comment: this is T. It means time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

Comment: Looks like a date "c" but without the last 9 chars. https://3v4l.org/N9Tdm

Comment: Ok to be fair: The question is bad. I don't really understand the downvotes on the answers though. Downvoting for the sake of answering a bad question seems a bit extreme..

Comment: I agree @icecub. Offtopic: Hi man! :P

Comment: @RonnieOosting Hello :) Just inquiring about it. I'd love to hear the reason behind the downvotes. Could only learn from it.

Comment: @icecub I do as well. I love to receive feedback if my answer seems not right instead of just a downvote, so i can lean from it.

Comment: I learnt a lot from you guys. thanks.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think it's because you should not encourage bad questions. But I think that downvoting the answerer does not help in any way. Lower the rep needed close vote/delete vote and the bad questions will not last long enough to get answers. In this case OP has been a member 1.5 years and 15 questions. He should know better. The only reason he does not know better is probably because his questions has been answered in the past and not closed/deleted fast enough. In my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do it for you:

```
<?php 
$date = '2017-12-31 11:45:00';
$newdate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($date));
echo $newdate; // 2017-12-31T11:45
;?>
```

Documentation about `strtotime`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

**NOTE:**

`strtotime` max date is '19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC'.

**New solution:** *PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7*

Please consider to use the new DateTime function: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

**Example new DateTime:**

```
<?php

$d = new DateTime("9999-12-31"); 
$d->format("Y-m-d"); // "9999-12-31"

$d = new DateTime("0000-12-31"); 
$d->format("Y-m-d"); // "0000-12-31"

$d = new DateTime("-9999-12-31"); 
$d->format("Y-m-d"); // "-9999-12-31"

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite simply using the DateTime object provided with PHP

```
<?php

$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-12-31 11:45:00');
$newFormat = $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i');
echo $newFormat;
```

Result:

```
2017-12-19T11:45
```